# DevExpress GridControl + EntityFramework - Linq - Master Detail

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I coded

```
gridControl1.DataSource = (from c in dbContext.OPCabs select c).ToList();
```

worked fine to get Master Detail in the grid, but when I do

```
gridControl1.DataSource = (from c in dbContext.OPCabs select new { c.ID_OP, c.CLI_NOME, c.VAL_TOTAL, c.DAT_ENTREGA }).ToList();
```

doesn't work, what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: the second one is because it's an anonymous type list, convert it to a class model, and it should work

Comment: What is the type of 'c' in `from c in dbContext.OPCabs select c`?

Comment: It is alrealdy a class 
    [Table("OPCAB")]
    public class OPCab
    {
        [Key, ReadOnly(true)]
        [Display(Name = "Id OP")]
        public Int64 ID_OP { get; set; }
        [ReadOnly(true), Display(Name = "Id Cliente")]
        public int ID_CLI { get; set; }
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        public int ID_FUNC { get; set; }
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        public Int16? ID_TIPO { get; set; }
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        public DateTime DAT_FATURAMENTO { get; set; } ...

Comment: @iSR5 I tried gridControl1.DataSource = (from c in dbContext.OPCabs select new { int64 = c.ID_OP }).ToList(); but no success too, could you explain better your ideia to convert it to a class model?

Comment: `select new { c.ID_OP, c.CLI_NOME, c.VAL_TOTAL, c.DAT_ENTREGA }` this is anonymous type, and it is not OPCab type. you should do `select new OPCab { ...}` so it returns List<OPCab>. Or, define a DTO class if you want a custom view of `OPCab` then use it `select new OPCabDTO{...}`

Comment: Hi @iSR5 thanks for your reply, I updated the question with your sugestion, sorry I'm newby and I didn't understand yet, could you check what is wrong now?

Comment: @FernandoDonizetiIto ooh, sorry was a typo, do this `select new OPCab() {...}` on classes you must define the `()` otherwise it will be treated as a collection (like arrays).

Comment: @iSR5 bad news, even with DTO, same first problem with details: public class DTO
    {
        public Int64 ID_OP { get; set; }

        public static IEnumerable<DTO> getData()
        {
            OPContext dbContext = new OPContext();
            return (from c in dbContext.OPCabs select new DTO() { ID_OP = c.ID_OP }).ToList();
        }
    }

Comment: @FernandoDonizetiIto you need to include the `IEnumerable` property that has the inner view from `OPCabs` class. Currently, you're only reteriving `ID_OP` so it won't expand because there is no other reference to other views.

Comment: @iSR5 solved my problem with your help, in fact DTO was the answer, please publish you answer ok, thanks a lot!